# Android buttons

Tags: android, mobile

I am planning to do an app in android which plans to send text from mobiles built in messaging app. I know to use intent to call the messaging app. My question is once the mobile's messaging app is chosen to complete the action, instead of user pressing the send button to send the message, is there anyway to automatically send it immediately after messaging app is chosen without waiting for the user to click the send button. Like there are onclicklistener() to monitor the button clicks, I need to  know, is there any function that can make the 'send' button automatically to get clicked. In other words, I need 'send' button of messaging app to be caught in its onclicklistner() function without actually clicking it. Is there anyway to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya if u want to make button to click itself then use

```
btn.performClick();
```

or else just put all your required operation inside function and call after message app chosen.